# Functionality and operation

Tags: terminology, analysis, operation

I'm trying to do some analysis and when writing down a list of functionalities I realized I'm a bit fuzzy on the notion.

What can you consider as functionalities like, say, on this Stackoverflow page? Also, to distinguish between the two, how would you define an operation?

My understanding is that the former is something vague, synonymous with a feature or use-case, defining a distinct need/requirement without going into details. Whereas, the latter is something basic, perhaps a subset of the former, but I wouldn't say it's atomic since an operation could be composed of other operations.

Edit: Here's a link on the subject: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=17873

P.S: Functionality might not be the correct expression in English. If so, please confirm this. "Fonctionalité" is often used with respect to software in the French language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking forward to other answers, though I suspect this is more of a language issue than that there are universally defined meanings to these two terms, *functionality* and *operation*. Therefore, the following is to be taken as just my personal opinion.

To me, ***functionality*** (in the sense that you seem to be talking of, as opposed to the meaning of the word in the linked-to forum discussion) refers to use cases, that is, to something that your product/system offers for achieving some goal. It's not a specific action you can perform, but rather an abstract statement of what a system allows you to do. Related terms are *feature*, or *facility*. (Btw. I think for this meaning of the word "functionality", *feature* would be more appropriate.) For example, you could say:

> *"This site offers search functionality / has a search feature for finding previously published articles."*

---

An ***operation*** (or *action*?) on the other hand is far more specific. It's not something your system/product offers, but something that is actually *done* with it. You would probably be talking about operations when you can say exactly how it is to be performed, e.g.:

> *"A search operation is performed by first entering keywords in this-and-that input field, followed by a click on the 'Go' button."*

---

If you take these two together, you could probably say that "functionality" is an abstract category for a number of concrete "operations" that go towards achieving the same general goal.

But I admit I cannot define the two terms more precisely, either; esp. with regards to choosing the right "granularity" for defining specific functionalties or features.

Comment: Quality feedback you've given there. I agree with you, it would be more appropriate to use the word feature. Also the way you describe operations makes me think of the arrowed lines used in sequence diagrams. In some methodologies this just happens to be the next step after defining use-cases.

Comment: @James, I should add that I didn't have sequence diagrams in the back of my mind when I wrote this answer; I don't even know much about them. So perhaps this "coincidence" means that my answer isn't too far off...? I hope I could help a bit.